# IBM Worklight - implemeting custom back/forward buttons

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, back-button

In my application i'm creating a `WL.TabBar` object for iOs and Android environments, like a navigation menu. To emulate the back-button of jquery i'm using a simple function like this

```
function back(){
   history.back();
   return false;
}

function forward(){
   history.forward();
   return false;
}
```

in iOs emulator it works but in Android no. I'm using an Android 2.2 virtual device.

EDIT:
here is the code on `android/js/[AppName].js` file, also the same of iOs environment.

```
function wlEnvInit(){
wlCommonInit();
// Environment initialization code goes here

   navigation.init();
   navigation.addItem("item1",back,"Back",{});
   navigation.addItem("item2",forward,"Forward",{});
   navigation.setVisible(true);

}

var navigation = WL.TabBar;

function back(){
   window.history.back();
   return false;
}

function forward(){
   window.history.forward();
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this code in the context of WL.TabBar? Like, arrow-style buttons at the bottom of the screen? You can try to take the code from the following sample and adjust it to fit yours: Building a multi-page application - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#client-basics

Comment: Do you see any errors in LogCat?

Comment: @IdanAdar the example in your comment refers to a multi-page application with more than one `.html` file. I use a single file with `data-role: page` and an id for each page. I saw the LogCat but there are no errors, when i press the button of the tab it shows me this message `Trying to fire onNativeReady onMessage(onNativeReady,null) onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///data/data/com.Discovergin_Ragusa/files/www/default/Discovergin_Ragusa.html)`

Comment: @IdanAdar I also installed `.apk` on my android phone (4.0.4) and it works. It seems to be a problem of android api version..

Comment: Please add a fuller implementation to the question (the WL.TabBar code).

Comment: @IdanAdar i posted the code as answer, take a look!

Comment: @IdanAdar sorry, i did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem seems to be unique to Android 2.x.  Your code works fine on Android 4.x.  For some reason, windows.back()/windows.forward() has no effect when called directly out of the tab bar click handler on Android 2.x.  You can work around this by using a short timeout:

```
function back() {
setTimeout(function() {
    window.history.back();
}, 100);
return false;
}

function forward() {
setTimeout(function() {
    window.history.forward();
}, 100);
return false;
}
```